# In UICollectionView, cells order are jumbled, along with the text field values present in it after scrolling though the collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

My UICollectionView cells are not in order after I scroll through the collecion view.

Cells Sample - There will be more than 12 cells

[image]

For example, the image above is a sample of a cell. This cell holds multiple textfields, labels and buttons.

After entering datas to each cell's textfields, labels, and button, when I scroll towards the end of the collection view, either:

1. Datas in a random cell are lost
2. Cells orders are jumbled (or)
3. Cells disappear

Code:

```
extension SampleViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SampleCollectionViewCell;

        cell.label1.text = String(indexPath.row)

        return cell;
    }
}
```

I have a functionality to add new cell,

```
let index = IndexPath(item: list.count, section: 0)
list.append(Fields(itemNumber: list.count))
self.CardsCollectionView.insertItems(at: [index])
```

And when a new cell is added after an existing cell is deleted, the deleted values appeared in the newly created cell.

Also to delete a random cell on swipe

```
self.CardsCollectionView.deleteItems(at: [index])
```

My CollectionViewCell,

```
class MySampleCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var dropdown: DropDown!
    @IBOutlet weak var field1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var field2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var field3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
}
```

I have tried all the possible methods I could think of.

Comment: The code you posted makes no attempt to populate a cell with any data other than showing its index path. If you need help you need to post the actual code that isn't working as expected.

Comment: Use the prepareForReuse method on the cell to reset the labels/textfields before they are used again. should solve your issue

Comment: @Scriptable when prepareforreuse is used, scrolling back and forth removes values provided in initial cells

Comment: @rmaddy could you please elaborate? above code pretty much covers my entire code and Due to confidentiality reason, i am not able to post my real code

Comment: @OnkarKalpavriksha thats exactly what it is supposed to do, reset the state of the  cell, ready for reuse again. as rmaddy said, the code shown only sets a label value to the indexPath.row value

Comment: The code you posted does not put any data in any cell. The `cellForItemAt` method only sets a single label and it sets it to the row number, not any of your data. So there is no way that the code you posted can possibly result in any jumbled data.

Comment: @rmaddy we will be entering data in each cell and then datas will be retrieved from each cell and store it in a list

Comment: The labels and buttons need their text set in `cellForRowAt`. And the text fields need to be populated in `cellForRowAt` from the data stored in the list.

Comment: @rmaddy labels are calculated based on the datas entered in 2 other fields and button names are set in storyboard,.......                                
             cell.field1.text =list[indexPath.row].field1

             cell.field2.text =list[indexPath.row].field2............. does this help?

Comment: @rmaddy was that helpful? or more information is required?